# Localhost setup to develop .NET MVC web application having Windows Authentication on a PC that isn't joined to a domain

Tags: localhost, windows-authentication

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC web application that will eventually be deployed to a server that is joined to our domain, and accessed by PCs (that are NOT joined to the domain) via VPN. I'd like for future developers not to have to disable Windows Authentication in the application in order to run it on localhost, but I'm not sure how to make that work / how to get the app to "authenticate" users when it's running on localhost. I tried logging into the Windows Security popup that I get with Windows Authentication enabled using users set up on the local PC who were members of a group on the local PC, and including that usergroup in the Authorize attribute on the controller as follows (of course with the real pc name, pc group, network domain and network group for my environment substituted in the string)

```
[Authorize(Roles="LocalPCName\\LocalPCGroup,NetworkDomain\\NetworkGroup")]
```

but that doesn't work - the login is not accepted - the popup just refreshes, clearing out the values I entered.

I enabled Windows Authentication by:
1) Adding  to the system.web section of my web.config and 
2) In IIS for the site, disabling Anonymous Authentication and enabling Windows Authentication.
3) Adding the aforementioned Authorize attribute to my base controller class.

When login didn't work that way, I also tried adding this config to my web.config, which also had the same result (a login popup that does not accept logins of a local user having access to a local group with the name configured in the Authorize attribute).

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
        name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"
        applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Is there something wrong with my Windows Authentication setup? Is there some way to make Windows Authentication "work" for localhost on a pc that isn't connected to a domain?

Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I am able to make windows authentication run on my local machine by adding the following to web.config. This made the application allow local users having the specified LocalPCGroup membership to access the application. Is that the correct approach?

    <authorization>
      <allow roles="LocalPCGroup"/>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>